# Display the table records of an Access database using table1 primary which is the foreign key in table 2

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access-2010

I have two tables in the same MS Access database, one called `Consultant Doctor` and the other is `Patients`. The primary key in `Consultant Doctor` is `DoctorID`, which is linked to the `DoctorID` in `Patients`.

The user inputs the patients ID and it should show his/her doctors information.

This is my code, I don't know how to link them together

```
        int anInteger;
        anInteger = Convert.ToInt32(textBox9.Text);
        anInteger = int.Parse(textBox9.Text);

        sConnection = 
        "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" +               "DataSource=hospital database.accdb";
        dbConn = new OleDbConnection(sConnection);
        dbConn.Open();

        sql = 
        "SELECT * FROM Consultant Doctor INNERJOIN      Patients ON Consultant Doctor.DoctorID =    Patients.DoctorID";
        dbCmd = new OleDbCommand();
        dbCmd.CommandText = sql;
        dbCmd.Connection = dbConn;
        dbCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("pID", anInteger);
        dbReader = dbCmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (anInteger == 101)
        {
            listBox3.Items.Add(dbReader["PatientID"]);
            listBox3.Items.Add(dbReader["DoctorName"]);
            listBox3.Items.Add(dbReader["DoctorAddress"]);
            listBox3.Items.Add(dbReader["Specialization"]);
            listBox3.Items.Add(dbReader["WardID"]);
            listBox3.Items.Add(dbReader["TeamID"]);
        }
```

As you can see, I tried to use inner join which doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is your only problem, but the syntax for an inner join should be `INNER JOIN`, not `INNERJOIN`.

ETA:  A couple of other things:

- You need to perform a `.Read()` on `dbReader` before attempting to access the values in the reader.  When it opens, a reader is positioned just before the first record, and there is no "current" record.  Performing `dbReader.Read()` will read the first record and make it available.
- Reading your code, it looks as if you expect `anInteger` to have a different value than the one you place in it at the top of the code.  But your SQL won't set it, and when you add the parameter, you aren't indicating that it's an output parameter.
- At the point you test `anInteger`, it's going to be equal to the value of `textBox9.Text`.  So it's only going to be equal to 101 if that's what the user entered.  Are you sure this is the logic you have in mind?

Comment: Also the table name includes a space, so bracket that name: `FROM [Consultant Doctor] INNER JOIN Patients ON [Consultant Doctor].DoctorID = Patients.DoctorID`

Comment: @HansUp True!  I missed that!

Answer (score 1):

Your sql is wrong. You need to spell correctly the INNER JOIN clause, but you also need to add a WHERE statement to identify your patient id

```
sql = 
    "SELECT * FROM [Consultant Doctor] " + 
    "INNER JOIN Patients ON [Consultant Doctor].DoctorID = Patients.DoctorID " +
    "WHERE Patients.PatientID = @pID";
```

Of course, as pointed by the other answers, you need to execute a Read method on the OleDbDataReader otherwise you cannot try to read anything from it. Other problems are present here and need to be fixed..

```
int anInteger;
anInteger = Convert.ToInt32(textBox9.Text);
anInteger = int.Parse(textBox9.Text);

sql = "SELECT * FROM [Consultant Doctor] " + 
       "INNER JOIN Patients ON [Consultant Doctor].DoctorID = Patients.DoctorID " +
       "WHERE Patients.PatientID = @pID";
sConnection =  "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=hospital database.accdb";
using(OleDbConnection dbConn = new OleDbConnection(sConnection))
using(OleDbCommand dbCmd = new OleDbCommand(sql dbConn))
{
    dbConn.Open();
    dbCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("pID", anInteger);
    using(OleDbDataReader dbReader = dbCmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        if(dbReader.Read())
        {
             listBox3.Items.Add(dbReader["PatientID"]);
             listBox3.Items.Add(dbReader["DoctorName"]);
             listBox3.Items.Add(dbReader["DoctorAddress"]);
             listBox3.Items.Add(dbReader["Specialization"]);
             listBox3.Items.Add(dbReader["WardID"]);
             listBox3.Items.Add(dbReader["TeamID"]);
        }
    }
 }
```

The [using statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) will help to close and dispose objects used in the block of code also in case of exceptions

Comment: i have tried your code, but it keeps giving me an error with the dbConn.Open(); the error message is: Could not find installable ISAM. and when i tried placing it somewhere else it gives me another error message saying: ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed.

Comment: `Data Source` (not sure if it is the cause but the [connection string examples](http://www.connectionstrings.com/access/) have a space in between)